# How can the following code be used to rearrange column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Trying to understand that how does the following code rearranges the columns of the resultant dataframe as per the other dataframe.

```
df_with_intercept = df_with_intercept[df_scorecard['Feature_names'].values]
```

Please note that `'Feature names'` column in `df_scorecard` has all the column names used in `df_with_intercept` with some scores against it.

Above code just rearranged the columns in `df_with_intercept` to match the order of rows in `'Feature names'`.

This is being done to enable dot multiplication of relevant variables with each other.

```
df_scorecard['Feature_names']

inputs_test_with_ref_cat_w_intercept = \ 
   inputs_test_with_ref_cat_w_intercept[df_scorecard['Feature name'].values]
```

Comment: Can you please give us some more details? like the content of the lists/dictionaries?

Comment: Hey! Echoing the comment above, a bit more info might help with context but i've outlined an answer which might help explain how things could fit together

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help explain things a bit.

**Updating column names of one Pandas dataframe from the column of another dataframe**

Start with a dataframe of data

```
df_pokemon = pd.DataFrame({                                        
    "A": ["Eevee", "Vaporeon", "Flareon"],                                                               
    "C": ["Pichu", "Pikachu", "Raichu"]})
```

This produces a dataframe which looks like this

[image]

Create the dataframe which has the label names

```
df_labels = pd.DataFrame({                                        
    "X": ["Pikachu_line", "Eevvee_line"]})
```

This produces a dataframe which looks like this

[image]

I can use the X column from df_labels to replace the column names in df_pokemon

```
df_pokemon.columns = df_labels['X'].tolist()
```

Thus

[image]

**How to change the order of columns in one dataframe based one the data in another dataframes column**

Let say want to switch the columns in df_pokemon, we can do this.

I've created a new df_labels which has an updated order (pikachu and eevee are switched)

```
df_labels = pd.DataFrame({"X": ["Pikachu_line", "Eevvee_line"]})
```

I can use this data in column X to dictate the order in df_pokemon

```
df_pokemon[df_labels['X'].tolist()]
```

You will see the order of columns has changed

[image]